# Procesar formulario y mostrar errores AJAX-LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, ajax

estoy completamente perdido con el procesamiento de un formulario y la validacion dle mismo... Estoy usando ajax para procesar el formulario y debo mostrar los errores de validacion y el clasico mensaje de exito en el envio pero por mas que trato no logro hacer el proceso de muestra de los errores:

En mi controlador estoy asi:

public function enviarFormContacto(Request $request){

```
    //Validamos los campos del formulario
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'nombre' => 'required',
        'fono' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'mensaje' => 'required',
        'g-recaptcha-response' => 'required|captcha'
    ]);

    //Si hay errores los enviariamos a la vista
     if ($validator->fails()) {
        //return response()->json();
        $error = $validator->messages()->toJson();
    }

    //Envio del Correo electronico si se paso la validacion


   

    //dd($form);
    $correo = new ContactoMail($form);
    Mail::to('xxxxx')->send($correo);

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Form is successfully submitted!']);
```

*/
}

El ajax que estoy tratando de usar en la vista:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#form').on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    name = $('#nombre').val();
    email = $('#email').val();
    fono = $('#fono').val();
    mensaje = $('#mensaje').val();
    condicion = $('#condicion').val();

    $.ajax({
      url: "/sendMailContact",
      type:"POST",
      data:{
        "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        nombre:name,
        email:email,
        fono:fono,
        condicion:condicion,
        mensaje:mensaje,
      },
      success:function(data){
        console.log(data); //Its return your success message
      },

      error: function(data) {
          $('#nombreError').text(data.responseJSON.error.name);

       }

     });
    });

</script>
```

y el form (vista blade):

```
<section id="contacto" class="mt-5">

              <!-- Heading -->
              <h2 class="box text-center"> ¿DUDAS? ¿DESEA SABER ALGO MÁS?, ENTONCES ¡CONTACTESE CON NOSOTROS!</h2>
              <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" style="display:none">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>

            </div>

            @if ($message = Session::get('success'))

                <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">

                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>

                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>

                </div>

                @endif
              <form id="form" {{-- role="form"  -- action="{{ route('contacto.send') }}"  method="POST" --}}  class="p-5 formulario-contacto-principal">
                @csrf
                <div class="row mb-4">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 form-sm"> <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i><label for="nombre">Mi nombre es:</label>
                      <input type="text" id="nombre"  name="nombre" class="form-control" placeholder="Su Nombre y Apellido">
                      <span class="text-danger" id="nombreError"></span>
                    </div>

                      @if ($errors->has('nombre'))
                        <small class="form-text text-danger">
                            {{ $errors->first('nombre') }}
                        </small>
                    @endif
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6 form-sm"> <i class="fa fa-phone prefix"></i><label for="fono">Llámeme al:</label>
                        <input type="tel"  name="fono" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Ej: +569 11223344" >
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row mb-4">
                    <div class="col-lg-6  form-sm"> <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix"></i><label for="email">y escríbame a:</label>
                        <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="sucorreo@sudominio.cl" class="form-control form-control-sm" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6  form-sm"> <i class="fa fa-info-circle prefix"></i><label for="condicion">Me identifico como:</label>
                        <select name="condicion" id="condicion" class="form-control form-control-sm">
                            <option value="Particular">Particular</option>
                            <option value="Emprendedor" selected>Emprendedor</option>
                            <option value="Pyme">Pyme</option>
                            <option value="Empresa">Empresa</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="row mb-4">
                    <div class="col-lg-12  form-sm"> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i><label for="mensaje">Mi mensaje:</label>
                        <textarea type="text"  name="mensaje" class="md-textarea form-control form-control-sm" rows="6" placeholder="Gracias por contactarnos!"></textarea>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row mb-4">
                    <div class="col-lg-12  form-sm" id="captcha"> <i class="fa fa-comments"></i><label for="recaptcha">Verificación Humana:</label>
                       {{--  {!! htmlFormSnippet() !!} --}}
                    {{--    {!! NoCaptcha::renderJs() !!} --}}
                       {!! app('captcha')->display() !!}
                    </div>
                    @if ($errors->has('g-recaptcha-response'))
                    <small class="form-text text-danger">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('g-recaptcha-response') }}</strong>
                    </small>
                    @endif
                                </div>

                  <div class="row mb4">
                    <div class="text-center mt-4">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success save-data" onclick="submitForm()">Save</button>
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success">ENVIAR CONSULTA<i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
                    </div>

                  </div>


              </form>
              <span class="success" style="color:green; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"></span>
                      <!-- Form contact -->
                  </div>
                  <!--Grid column-->
              </div>
              <!--Grid row-->
            </div>
```

Que me estare pasando por alto?

Saludos a todos

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? ¿Miraste la consola del navegador, la del red, qué error te da?

Comment: @gaidyjg hola, cero errores en consola ni en el network

Comment: no se van a mostrar los errores por la variable de session porque estas haciendo la peticion asincrona, debes manejar los errores con el catch del ajax